# Test typeof in javascript along with number variable

Tags: javascript

Why if I write the below script the value of variable f is 2016 ?

```
var year = 2016;
var g = 'foo';
var f = typeof g != 'undefined' && year;
```

Comment: What about it? `typeof g != 'undefined'` will always be `true` and you'll get the value of `year`.

Comment: yes but the value of f  is 2016

Comment: Exactly. He said you'll get "the value of year", and you set the value of year to 2016.

Comment: "you'll get the value of year" means the `f` variable is `2016`.

Comment: Right... What's the problem? When using operators like that, you get the result of the last truthy value or you get `false`.

Comment: @MikeC: You'll only get `false` if `false` is one of the operands.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True (ha). More accurately, you'll get the last falsy value, as you've explained in your answer.

Comment: @MikeC: Well, you'll get the last value. It may not be falsy. For instance, it isn't in the OP's scenario above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well yeah. I meant to imply you would get the last falsy value if a falsy value was present.

Comment: @MikeC: Ah, gotcha.

Answer (score 7):

Because `&&` is a very interesting operator in JavaScript: Unlike some other languages, it doesn't result in `true` or `false` (necessarily). Instead, the result of `&&` is the value of its left operand if that's *falsy*,<sup>1</sup> or the value of its right operand otherwise.

It works like this:

1. Evaluate the left-hand operand (in your case, `typeof g != 'undefined'`).
2. If that value is *falsy*, that's the result of the operation and we stop here.
3. If that value is *truthy*,<sup>2</sup> evaluate the right-hand operand (`year)` and make that the result of the operation.

Following it through for your example:

1. Evaluate `typeof g != 'undefined'`. Since `typeof g` is `'string'`, and `'string' != 'undefined'`, that's `true`.
2. `true` is not falsy so we don't stop.
3. Evaluate `year` and make that the result.

So `f` gets 2016 (the value of `year`) assigned to it.

`&&` has an equally-interesting cousin, `||`, on which I've written a blog post about this behavior: [*JavaScript's Curiously-Powerful OR Operator (||)*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)

---

<sup>1</sup> *Falsy* values are values that coerce to `false` when treated as booleans. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false.

<sup>2</sup> *Truthy* values are values that aren't *falsy* (they coerce `true` when treated like a boolean).

Note: The way values act when you use them as booleans is **not** the same way they behave if you *compare* them to booleans. `"foo"` is a truthy value, but `"foo" == true` and `"foo" === true` are both **`false`**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the value of `f` will be `2016`.

Let's break down your code.

```
typeof g != 'undefined' //returns true
```

In the case of logical operator, the final value will be returned. In your case

```
true && year //returns 2016
```

As the `&&` is satisfied, the final value(year) will b returned and assigned to `f`

Answer (score 1):

The && operator always returns the last thing it tested, and because in your case that's  year, it will return the value of `year`.

The && never converts variables into booleans, it only checks if it's a truthy value.

Comment: *"The && operator always returns the last thing it tested"* It doesn't really *test* its second operand, and yet, that's got to be one of the clearest ways I've seen that put. Nice one. Going to have to let that inspire future explanations to people about this, trying to tweak it slightly without losing the wonderful simplicity.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator evaluates to its left argument if that is falsey, otherwise it evaluates to its right argument.

Since `g` is *not* undefined, `typeof g != 'undefined'` is true, `typeof g != 'undefined' && year` evaluates to `year` which is 2016.

(This differs from some other languages, where the result of logical operators like `&&` or `||` will always  be a boolean, but this is not the case with JavaScript.)

Comment: `typeof g != "undefined"` is true, not false

Comment: @Bálint Right sorry, I did a typo there. Thanks!